# The latest version (6.0.20) of Akavache seems to be partly broken when used in Xamarin.iOS?

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, akavache

I was originally trying to fetch and cache an image using `BlobCache.LocalMachine.LoadImageFromUrl(someURL)`, but I found that it
just stopped responding after I called this method. (Yes, I've set `BlobCache.ApplicationName`, I even called `BlobCache.EnsureInitialized()`, and the SQL3 lib wasn't stripped by the linker.) So I did some experiments and tried to find out what was wrong.
After several hours of testing I found that only these methods should work in my circumstances:

1.

```
BlobCache.LocalMachine.DownloadUrl(someURL).Wait(); // Can fetch the right image file but it won't store it into cache; The cache disappears if I restart the app
var image = BlobCache.LocalMachine.LoadImage(someURL).Wait().ToNative(); // This part is good
```

2.

```
BlobCache.LocalMachine.InsertObject<string>(key, value).Wait();
var value = BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<string>(key).Wait(); // This functions well; I can get the correct value right away after a restart
```

Also, whenever I use await in my code, it falls to infinite deadlock(?). Say, `var value = await BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetObject<string>(key);`. (Of course I've imported `System.Reactive.Linq`.) The possible workaround to me is to use `wait()` or `subscribe()` instead.

BlobCache.LocalMachine.GetOrFetchObject() won't work either.

P.S.: I have the latest Xamarin.iOS & Mono build on my VS Mac.

So did I miss anything that's important when using Akavache in Xamarin.iOS?
Please enlighten me.

I've posted an issue [here](https://github.com/reactiveui/Akavache/issues/424).

Comment: Did it works fine on older version?

Comment: @LucasZ Sorry I was just starting to use it so I never had a chance to test older versions Orz. Please refer to the link above for more info.